# What is prewhitening filter mode?

Tags: filters, z-transform, autoregressive-model

In this [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3319667_Exploiting_temperature_dependency_in_the_detection_of_NQR_signals), the following prewhitening filter is described:

$$
C(z) = \sum_{k=0}^n c_{k}z^{-k}
$$

where $n$ and $c_k$ are known.

The paper also describes the values $C(\lambda_{k})$, with $\lambda_{k}$ complex number, as the above filter "evaluated at the mode $\lambda_{k}$".

**Does anybody understand what the $C(\lambda_{k})$ values represent (what do they mean by a filter mode)? Are they just $C(z)$ computed by replacing $z$ with $\lambda_{k}$?**

Comment: not to be contrary but your equation is a FIR filter not a AR filter.

Comment: I meant prewhitening instead of AR. Thanks!